# Way to determine most popular Homebrew packages?

Tags: homebrew

Is there a way to determine which Homebrew packages have been installed the most times, either in the recent past or all-time? It would make it easier to determine which formulae are the most useful, and to discover new software I may not have heard of. Currently, I just use homebrew when I find out "I need to install this" for some dependency.

Comment: Good Q - [I asked the same on Superuser](http://superuser.com/questions/775331/how-can-i-browse-through-homebrews-formulae-according-to-popularity-download), to no avail thus far though.

Comment: We have the information for bottled formulae but not from the source ones. Releasing the anonymised downloads data is on our (long) TODO list.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Homebrew has been collecting anonymized analytics data and is sharing it at https://brew.sh/analytics

Sample results:

```
#1  openssl@1.1 2,315,158   2.54%
#2  sqlite  2,159,426   2.37%
#3  python@3.9  1,933,232   2.12%
#4  gdbm    1,426,774   1.57%
#5  icu4c   1,332,610   1.46%
#6  readline    1,302,327   1.43%
#7  mpdecimal   1,291,791   1.42%
#8  glib    1,149,928   1.26%
#9  node    1,100,823   1.21%
#10 m4  1,078,010   1.1
```

Here is a list of the most popular packages that people explicitly install (not as a dependency of something else):
https://brew.sh/analytics/install-on-request/

Here is a list of most frequently installed packages, which may include dependencies:
https://brew.sh/analytics/install/