# How to generate list of Homebrew formulas/packages sorted by "most recently updated" (by package provider)?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, homebrew, darwin

How can one generate a list of [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) all formulas/packages sorted by "most recently updated" (by package provider)?

I see no such sort/report at https://formulae.brew.sh/analytics. Maybe I missed something?

I can effectively generate some version of this report ever time I run a `brew update`... but that only provides me the updated-formulae since I last `brew updated`-ed, I think? I want to instead visit a website or run a command-line command (or some similar gizmo) that shows me a reasonably-updated report of all-most-recently-updated formulae.

Similar but distinctly-different questions:

1. [List all Homebrew formulas?](https://superuser.com/questions/390191/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-all-formulas-available-for-homebrew)
2. [List most-popular Homebrew formulas (#1)?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/142839/way-to-determine-most-popular-homebrew-packages)
3. [List most-popular Homebrew formulas (#2)?](https://superuser.com/questions/775331/how-can-i-browse-through-homebrews-formulae-according-to-popularity-download)

Answer (score 1):

Open this folder in Finder:

`/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula`

**⌘ ⇧ G** in Finder will bring up a “Go To Folder…” dialog box. You can then paste the path from above into the box.

Then press **⌘ 2** to switch to list view and then click “Date Modified”.

Comment: I know you're an under-the-hood kind of guy so [this answer I posted](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/304345/show-installation-date-of-packages-installed-with-homebrew/432218#432218) might be useful to you as well.